# Changing \url{...} font

Tags: fonts, hyperref, urls

`\url{...}` produces a rather wide monospace font. It often does not fit into text width.

If I wish to make `\url{...}` another font (such as maybe the same font as the text font), how to do it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`\url` comes from package `url` (loaded by `hyperref`). `\urlstyle` configures the font. The same font:

```
\urlstyle{same}
```

This means, no special font is set and the current font is used for the URL.

Other pre-defined styles:

- `\urlstyle{rm}`: The font `\rmfamily` is used.
- `\urlstyle{sf}`: The font `\sffamily` is used.
- `\urlstyle{tt}`: This is the default: `\ttfamily`.

See also the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf).