# How do I prevent automatic maths styling?

Tags: bibliographies

Please refer to the images.  I'm using overleaf.

[image: Overleaf report]

[image: Bad output of reference link]

Reference in bib file

```
@book{addie_dalibor,
  title={ADDIE model for development of e-courses},
  author={ Drljaca Dalibor and Branco Latinovic and Zeljko Stankovic and Dragan Cvetkovic},
   year={2017},
   DOI={10.15308/Sinteza-2017-242-247},
   url={https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316463437_ADDIE_model_for_development_of_e-courses},
   Urldate = {Jan 28, 2011},
  }
```

Comment: Try `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` in your preamble and if the url still doesn't break nice check this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115820/120578

Comment: Unrelated to tex, but instead of linking to reserchgate, you should better link to the original website of the paper http://portal.sinteza.singidunum.ac.rs/paper/524

Comment: You are right samcarter, i will eventually go through the references at the right time and check them one by one.  Thanks for the suggestion. Appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\usepackage{hyperref}` (put it before `\begin{document}` in your `.tex` file if you aren't using it already, **not** in your `.bib` file), you can wrap your URL in `\url{}` to avoid the underscores being read as "LaTeX" commands:

```
@book{addie_dalibor,
  title={ADDIE model for development of e-courses},
  author={ Drljaca Dalibor and Branco Latinovic and Zeljko Stankovic and Dragan Cvetkovic},
   year={2017},
   DOI={10.15308/Sinteza-2017-242-247},
   url={\url{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316463437_ADDIE_model_for_development_of_e-courses}},
   Urldate = {Jan 28, 2011},
  }
```

Comment: I already had the hyperref package.  Using the url wrapper worked.  however, it appears the font has changed and looks a little fancy.  how to prevent that?

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad you can have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261435/182889) answer.