Font in DOI / URL in references is off
im trying to get my bibliography into one style. The problem is, that DOI and URL have some weird font family and size, and i cant get that changed.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem\cite{test}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

with the source
@misc{test,
    author = "John Doe",
    doi = "1232132",
    url = "https://www.google.com",
}

This results in the said problem (s. figure).
How can i make the font the same family and size as in any other text?


\urlstyle{rm} may helps you

Do you mean the font of the word "URL" or the font of the url itself?

Thank you for your answers, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, both

It would be better, if you'd only ask about one problem per question. Mixing two makes it hard to close your question as duplicate.

Duplicate for the font of the actual url: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261435/36296

To change the word doi/url: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508980/36296

Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, i will remember to split those questions up next time.

From your provided links, i used \DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{DOI:\space\nolinkurl{#1}} \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL:\space\nolinkurl{#1}} which solves the problem of the label. Thank you!

@JulianK Please keep in mind, that multiple capital letters in a row will look larger than the surrounding text even if they have the same size. Acronyms often look better in a smaller font or in small caps.

Please always try to focus on one question per question.

In general, almost all the Hyperlink font was fixed as Mono font family, if you want to change, you can use \urlstyle{rm}, and the MWE is:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{\protect\normalfont\uppercase{DOI}}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \mkbibacro{\protect\normalfont\uppercase{URL}}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\urlstyle{rm}

Lorem\cite{test}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


Hi, thank you so much, how can i change the font of the label "DOI" or "URL" itself?

Check the updated answer, this will works but it needs more fine tune, may some experts will suggest better method
